# How to inject SignalR hub to a regular class using SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, console-application, owin, signalr-hub, simple-injector

In a console app I'm using

- OWIN
- Signalr
- SimpleInjector

I have an **Engine** class which needs **NotificationHub** and NotificationHub needs **ClientWriter** to work. I managed to setup dependencies but it seems that the Engine cannot directly use the hub. Later I found out that the hub engine is using is different than the one clients are being connected to. Here are my files:

**Engine.cs**

```
 public class Engine
 {
     private readonly NotificationHub _hub;
     private readonly Timer _timer;

     public Engine(NotificationHub hub)
     {
         _hub = hub;
         _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
         _timer.Elapsed += (o, arg) =>
         {
             _timer.Enabled = false;
             Inform(arg.SignalTime.ToString());
             _timer.Enabled = true;
         };
         _timer.Start();
     }

     public void Inform(string str)
     {
         try
         {
             var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("notification");
             ctx.Clients.All.Notify($"{str} ====="); //works why?
             _hub.Inform(str); // does not work why?
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
         }
     }
 }
```

**NotificationHub.cs**

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    ClientWriter _writer;
    public NotificationHub(ClientWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"connected {Context.ConnectionId}");

        Clients.All.Notify($"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined");
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public DateTime Inform(string msg)
    {
        _writer.Received(msg);
        return DateTime.Now;
    }

}
```

**ClientWriter.cs**

```
public class ClientWriter
{

   public void Received(string arg)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(arg);
   }
}
```

**HubActivator**

```
class SimpleInjectorSignalRHubActivator : IHubActivator
    {
        Container _container;
        public SimpleInjectorSignalRHubActivator(Container container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }
        public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(descriptor.HubType) as IHub;
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var _container = new Container();
    _container.RegisterSingleton<NotificationHub>();
    _container.RegisterSingleton<Engine>();
    _container.RegisterSingleton<ClientWriter>();

    var options = new StartOptions();
    options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:12345");
    using (var server = WebApp.Start(options, (app) =>
    {
        var activator = new SimpleInjectorSignalRHubActivator(_container);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IHubActivator), () => activator);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(NotificationHub), () => _container.GetInstance<NotificationHub>());

        app.RunSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true });
        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }))
    {
        var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("notification");
        var engine = _container.GetInstance<Engine>();
        engine.Inform("Engine has started");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong. Why the Engine is not able to send to the clients

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly is happening. Could you be more specific about "works" vs "doesn't work?" Like is `Engine::_hub` `null` or are things not functioning as expected in a certain way?

Comment: just comment out the works line and it doesn't work at all. Why does it have to use IHubContext and not the hub itself.